# The name 'textBoxFilePath' does not exist in the current context ERROR in c#

Tags: c#

This is a simple program of creating a form in c#

```
private void buttonOpenFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    openDialog.Filter = "Image Files (*.png, *.jpg) | *.png; *.jpg";
    openDialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Users\metech\Desktop";

    if (openDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        textBoxFilePath.Text = openDialog.FileName.ToString();
        pictureBox1.ImageLocation = textBoxFilePath.Text;
    }

}
```

I can t figure out why this error of 'textBoxFilePath' does not exist in the current context is occurring .

Comment: do you have the textBoxFilePath in the form?

Comment: make sure that "textBoxFilePath" is the name of your textBox.

Comment: `TextBox textBoxFilePath = new TextBox();` should be somewhere in your form.

Comment: Show us the content of the associated xyz.designer.cs

Comment: Well you certainly aren't declaring it in the code you have shown us. Are you sure you definitely have a control with that name? Bearing in mind that names are case sensitive as well...

Comment: textBoxFilePath.Text= openDialog.FileName.ToString();

Comment: Above line is giving error of not in context when I am compiling my form program in visual studio c# 2010 express . Please help .

Comment: I am coding a simple steganography program with the help of YouTube videos on c# in visual studio 2010 express , but I am stuck at above mentioned point